# Handling unordered arguments (params)

Tags: php, function, parameters, arguments

The best praticle to handle parameters (or arguments) in a functions it is about to know exactly what the function needs in a ordered list (see `func_get_args()`) so to get the corresponding variables (locale scope) and values.

What about if you know what you need as input inside a function but you don't know what are you are going to get? (How many arguments? What order? What type?)

I suppose that there could be different ways to do that and I've found myself the following code lines:

```
function myvars() {
    $vars = array( "firstname" => "string", "lastname" => "string", "age" => "int", "alive" => "bool" );
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        foreach($vars as $var => $type) {
            if (preg_match('/^' . $type . '/i', gettype($arg))) {
                $$var = $arg;
                unset($vars[$var]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    var_dump($firstname);
    var_dump($lastname);
    var_dump($age);
    var_dump($alive);
}

myvars(31, "Mark", true, "Green");
```

I would appriciate other snippets to work out this issue.

Comment: did you can pass an object (create an class that contain the right properties)

Comment: Think about using an options or params array like ``customFunction($params)`` where you're passing in key-value manner.

Comment: @deceze        It depens where the data (params) are from and where the data are going to.

Answer (score 0):

> On two occasions I have been asked, "Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put
>   into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?" ...
>   I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that
>   could provoke such a question.
>
> *—Charles Babbage, Passages from the Life of a Philosopher*

Function signatures and declarations are precisely to establish an interface or contract between two different parts of your code. Why would you ever declare a function without any specification and why would you ever call that function without any idea of what you're doing and why would you still expect to get a sensible result?

Have your function declare its parameters by name, or at least accept an array or object with named keys. You can't get code structure without structuring your code. Your example code is non-deterministic, since you're getting two strings and cannot distinguish them from one another. There's no guarantee you can make that this function always produces the correct output.

Comment: Sometimes I wrote functions inside a class such `load()` where the object sets its own propeties loading them from a file or _building itself_ using strings, booleans, and integers or getting the values from other objects or assoc arrays. Best way should suggest to use diffent functions such `load_from_file($filename="")` or `load_from_string($title="", $text="", $tags=array(), $ready=false)` or `load_from_object($someotherobject=null)` but one only function that can handle all the other ones depending the input params sometimes it could work as well. PS. Gorgeous quote!

Comment: *If* all your parameters are of a different type, preferably if they're all their own class types, this can work. This can be used in dependency injection containers to save some typing, for instance. However, if you get two strings... by definition you have no clue which is which, and there's no programmatic way to find out.

Comment: You are totally right. Strings could be handled checking them via `preg_match()` to know if they are path_to_file, a word, a phrase, a multiline text and so on. Elsewhere you can assume their meanings depending by their queue (1st string is the first name, 2nd string is the last name). Anyway this kind of coding causes many headaches! But when it works as expected it renders a lot of satisfactions.

Comment: I've been in the "works automagically" world for a while. Believe me: it sucks. Sooner or later it will. The tiny bit of automagic something or other is rarely offsetting the headaches it will eventually cause. Properly structuring your code and using decent design patterns is a much better long-term solution.

Comment: Yes, I believe you so much. Haim Evgi (above) has suggested a basic alternative to my question and it is about to pass an object (or assoc array) then parse it. As smart as too easy that I could not think about that! You are right and better design patterns should be the right way to write code.